# Removing zero values from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

**Problem**

I'm pushing values from my JavaScript functions and filling an array with objects.
what I would like to happen is remove key + Value pairs that are zero.

example of return array

```
[Object percent: 516 unit: -10.689124404913258
 Object percent: 516  unit: -9.011227255423254
 Object percent: 561  unit: -12.669770888525518
 Object percent: 6516 unit: -15.99180968320506 
 Object percent: 0  unit: 0]
```

**JavaScript**

```
my_arr = []

  for(var i = my_arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(array[i] === 0) {
       array.splice(i, 1);
    }
   return my_arr;
}
```

Comment: Just update the if condition from `array[i] === 0` to `array[i]['percent'] === 0 || array[i]['unit'] === 0`. Change the || to && if both properties should be 0 for the object to be removed.

Comment: why not prevent pushing if values are not sufficient?

Comment: @NinaScholz could you show how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove items from your array which has price and unit you can use this.

```js
var items = [
    { percent: 516, unit: -10.689124404913258 }, 
    { percent: 516, unit: -9.011227255423254 }, 
    { percent: 561, unit: -12.669770888525518 }, 
    { percent: 6516, unit: -15.99180968320506 }, 
    { percent: 0, unit: 0 }
];

items = items.filter(i => i.percent && i.unit);

console.log(items);
```

**BTW** the main problem with yours is that you return inside the loop which will stop the loop in the very first turn.
I don't even believe that your code works even for a while because using `return` out side the function scope i kind of error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement

Comment: this would filter out all falsy values, but OP specifically said only 0s.

Comment: @nem035 Your right but OP's example is about to deal with numbers.

Comment: @mortezaT Love your approach, whoever I getting a Syntax error in IE any thoughts on how to get over this currently your solution is written like this  $('#sub').click(function() {
items = my_arr.filter(i => i.percent && i.unit);
  console.log(items);
 })

Comment: @C.Kelly I think this is because IE is not supporting `ES6`. Just change the lamda (`i => i.percent && i.unit`) with an anonymous function (`function(i){ return i.percent && i.unit; }`)

Answer (score 2):

Just try with:

```
my_arr.filter(function(element){
  return element.percent && element.unit;
});
```

If `percent` and `unit` properties equal `0`, it will give false result and will be filtered out from the results.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your source array looks like this...

```
var sourceArray = [
    { percent: 123, unit: -1 },
    { percent: 456, unit: -2 },
    { percent: 0, unit: 0 },
    { percent: 789, unit: -3 }
];
```

....then you can get a filtered array using the [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function:

```
var filteredArray = sourceArray.filter(function(item) {
    return item.percent || item.unit;
})
// => [
//  { percent: 123, unit: -1 },
//  { percent: 456, unit: -2 },
//  { percent: 789, unit: -3 }
//];
```

Note that this is checking that both `percent` **and** `unit` are zero before removing the item.  If you only need to check one of the values then you can modify the filter function (e.g. `return item.percent` if you only want to check `percent`)

Comment: You want `&&`, not `||` :)

Comment: @nem035 `&&` would filter out items where _either_ `percent` _or_ `unit` is falsey.  As per my edit, this only filters items where both `percent` _and_ `unit` are zero.  Not clear what OP was asking for!

Comment: OP said >  "what I would like to happen is remove key + Value pairs that are zero", so that seems like both to me :). You got my upvote regardless though, its a correct approach

Comment: Exactly.  Not "where `percent` is zero" nor "where `unit` is zero".  "That are zero" could be inferred to mean "where both are zero", "where either is zero" or where "one specific value is zero".  Based on his sample data I assumed he meant "where both are zero"

Comment: My apologies if I wasn't clear, it doesn't have to be both just whichever returns zero

Comment: @C.Kelly in that case you can use `&&` instead of `||` above.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a filter:

```
var filtered_array = my_arr.filter(function(el) { return el.percent > 0; });
```

of course you can include whatever other conditions you like - the filtered array contains all the elements where the callback function returns true.

Comment: filtered_array is returning an empty array?